# Reading SMS from PC

Tags: java, usb

Scenario : 1
Suppose there are two phones A and B. phone B sends a message to phone A. Phone A has that message in its inbox. Both the phones are nokia multimedia phones that can be connected with my laptop via nokia pc-suite.They can  also be connected via Bluetooth with my HP laptop.

Scenario : 2
A valid sim card of my local operator is inserted into a modem and the modem is connected with my laptop. I can read messages sent in that number(sim) by using the software provided with the modem.

Question:
The received text message will be the input of my java program. How can I read that message with my java program. Solution for any of the two scenarios will solve my problem.

It would be very helpful for me if someone provide me some resources regarding this issue. I am interested to implement it by java but it would be also helpful if the resources are not in java platform but relevant to my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect GSM modem built in Mobile Phone via bluetooth or RF232 connection, then send AT Commands. Pure java conenction functions should not be enough to make it possible. So you can use low level API coded by C programming language then connect it with Java applicatio via JNI.